# map entry key reference to constant value

Tags: xml, spring

By default I initialize map using `entry` for `Map` in xml like this

```
<entry key="key">
    <bean class="org.test.SimpleClass"/>
</entry>
```

However I've got several constants in my another class

```
class MyClass {
     public static String KEY_VAL = "String";
}
```

How to reference value `KEY_VAL` as `key` value for xml configuration?
I know about `util`

```
<util:constant static-field="org.test.MyClass.KEY_VAL" />
```

But how to apply it for `Map` entries?

Comment: Does this not work?  `<entry key="key">
  <util:constant static-field="some.class.OTHER_CONSTANT" />
</entry>`

Comment: @superbly that would use the static field as the _value_ for the map entry, the OP wants to use it as the _key_.

Comment: Got the question wrong. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the key as an element instead of an attribute:

```
<entry>
    <key>
        <util:constant static-field="org.test.MyClass.KEY_VAL" />
    </key>
    <bean class="org.test.SimpleClass"/>
</entry>
```

In fact the more typical `key="something"` and `key-ref="otherBean"` attributes are just shorthand for the "long" forms `<key><value>something</value></key>` and `<key><ref bean="otherBean"/></key>` respectively.